# How to select all files of a SQL Server database from blob folder?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, blob, filestream

I have a SQL Server database.

You can use the following script to create similar database:

```
CREATE DATABASE [test]
CONTAINMENT = NONE
ON PRIMARY 
   (NAME = N'test', FILENAME = N'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL14.SQLEXPRESS\MSSQL\DATA\test.mdf' , SIZE = 8192KB , MAXSIZE = UNLIMITED, FILEGROWTH = 65536KB ), 
   FILEGROUP [FS] CONTAINS FILESTREAM  DEFAULT
   (NAME = N'FS', FILENAME = N'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL14.SQLEXPRESS\MSSQL\DATA\FS' , MAXSIZE = UNLIMITED)
   LOG ON 
   (NAME = N'test_log', FILENAME = N'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL14.SQLEXPRESS\MSSQL\DATA\test_log.ldf', SIZE = 8192KB, MAXSIZE = 2048GB, FILEGROWTH = 65536KB )
GO
```

It's clear how to select all database files:

```
select * from sys.database_files

file_id     file_guid                            type type_desc                                                    data_space_id name                                                                                                                             physical_name                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    state state_desc                                                   size        max_size    growth      is_media_read_only is_read_only is_sparse is_percent_growth is_name_reserved is_persistent_log_buffer create_lsn                              drop_lsn                                read_only_lsn                           read_write_lsn                          differential_base_lsn                   differential_base_guid               differential_base_time  redo_start_lsn                          redo_start_fork_guid                 redo_target_lsn                         redo_target_fork_guid                backup_lsn
----------- ------------------------------------ ---- ------------------------------------------------------------ ------------- -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- ----- ------------------------------------------------------------ ----------- ----------- ----------- ------------------ ------------ --------- ----------------- ---------------- ------------------------ --------------------------------------- --------------------------------------- --------------------------------------- --------------------------------------- --------------------------------------- ------------------------------------ ----------------------- --------------------------------------- ------------------------------------ --------------------------------------- ------------------------------------ ---------------------------------------
1           07DE2F09-B9C3-4CC9-AC7F-C7BBEDBFE572 0    ROWS                                                         1             test                                                                                                                             C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL14.SQLEXPRESS\MSSQL\DATA\test.mdf                                                                                                                                                                                     0     ONLINE                                                       1024        -1          8192        0                  0            0         0                 0                0                        NULL                                    NULL                                    NULL                                    NULL                                    NULL                                    NULL                                 NULL                    NULL                                    NULL                                 NULL                                    NULL                                 NULL
2           25C00910-F2F0-48EF-8AE6-DB3E947DF0F3 1    LOG                                                          0             test_log                                                                                                                         C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL14.SQLEXPRESS\MSSQL\DATA\test_log.ldf                                                                                                                                                                                 0     ONLINE                                                       1024        268435456   8192        0                  0            0         0                 0                0                        NULL                                    NULL                                    NULL                                    NULL                                    NULL                                    NULL                                 NULL                    NULL                                    NULL                                 NULL                                    NULL                                 NULL
65537       DB6C446D-E1E1-4F5B-BC27-92168A94A92B 2    FILESTREAM                                                   2             FS                                                                                                                               C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL14.SQLEXPRESS\MSSQL\DATA\FS                                                                                                                                                                                           0     ONLINE                                                       0           -1          0           0                  0            0         0                 0                0                        36000000012900001                       NULL                                    NULL                                    NULL                                    NULL                                    NULL                                 NULL                    NULL                                    NULL                                 NULL                                    NULL                                 NULL

(3 rows affected)
```

Now let's create a table with blobs:

```
USE [test]

CREATE TABLE TestBlob
(
    [Id] [uniqueidentifier] ROWGUIDCOL NOT NULL UNIQUE, 
    [tbBin] VARBINARY(MAX) FILESTREAM NULL
)
GO
```

And put there some data:

```
USE [test]

INSERT INTO TestBlob (Id, tbBin)
    SELECT NEWID(), BulkColumn FROM OPENROWSET(Bulk 'C:\Everyone\small', Single_Blob) AS tb 

INSERT INTO TestBlob (Id, tbBin)
    SELECT NEWID(), BulkColumn FROM OPENROWSET(Bulk 'C:\Everyone\another', Single_Blob) AS tb
```

Now blob folder looks like this:

```
cmd> tree "C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL14.SQLEXPRESS\MSSQL\DATA\FS" /F

C:\PROGRAM FILES\MICROSOFT SQL SERVER\MSSQL14.SQLEXPRESS\MSSQL\DATA\FS
│   filestream.hdr
│
├───$FSLOG
└───f4bf1197-bb52-4246-95ba-4b7622065c19
    └───4cf08168-3853-4c3d-ada2-4a1ff8d19900
            00000024-000000b1-0002
            00000024-000000cd-0002
```

I need a T-SQL query to select all blob files of a database.

Here it's the following files (my database uses them):

```
00000024-000000b1-0002
00000024-000000cd-0002
```

Anyone could help me with that ?

I also know that it's possible to use undocumented stored procedure:

```
EXEC master.sys.xp_dirtree 'C:\PROGRAM FILES\MICROSOFT SQL SERVER\MSSQL14.SQLEXPRESS\MSSQL\DATA\FS',0,1;

subdirectory                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     depth       file
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- ----------- -----------
$FSLOG                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           1           0
f4bf1197-bb52-4246-95ba-4b7622065c19                                                                                                                                                                                                                             1           0
4cf08168-3853-4c3d-ada2-4a1ff8d19900                                                                                                                                                                                                                             2           0
00000024-000000b1-0002                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           3           1
00000024-000000cd-0002                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           3           1
filestream.hdr                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   1           1

(6 rows affected)
```

But it works with file system. I mean it doesn't consider if a file is used by the database or not.

Comment: "I need a t-sql query to select all blob files of a database." Why?

Comment: Why do you want this? This isn't just a blob, it's using filestream storage. Otherwise it would be stored inside the database data file. Simply querying the tables will return the blobs. The location those files is well known, in fact it was specified during installation. There's no reason to store them inside `Program Files` for example.

Comment: If you want to read those files as files, you *can* do so through the SQL client library you use. For ADO.NET for example, [you can use  SqlFileStream](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/sqlclient-streaming-support#sample----streaming-from-sql-server). You don't need to know their paths.

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft In genereal I need to sync each file which is used by a database to some storage

Comment: That would be possible and supported using FileTable, but not FileStream. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/blob/filetables-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I'm avoding any ORM impl

Comment: Nobody talked about ORMs. You haven't explained what you want to do yet

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft I work with a db as a client and can't change schema of the database.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I need to know which files are used by database and which are not, file created date and file updated date. Why do I need it ? I would like to sync(copy) all blob files of a database to different location.

Comment: Furthermore, if you try to access the files directly you'd have no idea what they contain. The logical path of those files is controlled by the database. You can use the [PathName](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-functions/pathname-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) function to find the logical UNC path eg `\\ServerName\MSSQLSERVER\v1\Archive\dbo\Records\Chart\A73F1`, which can be used to read that file

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Here I'm already working with a db which is online. I do not want to backup and restore it. Thanks for this Change Tracking idea it might help me

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I'm working with disc on physical layer, so I can check and apply only changes(like real syncing) for .mdf\.ldf\.ndf files(and it works pretty good actually). But I stuck with blob folder cause it might contain a lot of files - e.g. 1kk files the size of which is 1 KB

Comment: That's fake syncing. You can't treat databases like files. You have *no* idea whether a transaction is in progress, whether the file is in a consistent state. WIthout both the file and the log, you can't copy the database. People that tried to use rsync to "backup" databases found out they had no usable backup when the time came

Comment: If you want to replicate a database, use replication. SQL Server supports a *lot* of different replication types. If you care about high availability, use database mirroring at least. Or use **real** backups. Unlike other databases, SQL Server performs real data-level backups, without locking the database. Even SQL Server Express has the equivalent of MySQL Enterprise Hot Backups. Backups include FILESTREAM blobs too

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I needn't know whether a transaction is in progress or not. What I'm doing is completely different - I'm maintaining a database online(using iscsi remote mount so the db is really online and you can write there) and at the same time I'm syncing database files to file system(and these files are just files - like I'm preparing db files in real location in file system). And when sync is completed more less, I'm detaching the db, making final sync and attaching the same db but from different paths - those which are on file system.

Comment: @isxaker `I needn't know whether a transaction is in progress or not.` then just generate a random set of bytes the same size as the file, because that's what you get. You **DO CARE** about transactions, otherwise you get an inconsistent database, with data pages data from different points in time. If you have to detach ... why not just use a *backup*? It has no downtime for starters. If you use compression, it takes far less space than the actual database.

Comment: @isxaker besides, you already know what the files are - it's all files in that folder. If you [ask the database](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1878/how-to-detach-and-attach-a-sql-server-filestream-enabled-database/) it will tell you it's all files in that folder. If anyone puts irrelevant files in there, it's just sloppy management, no different than someone modifying the `mdf` files directly. Just don't do that.

Comment: Anyway, I'm also voting to move that to `dba.stackexchange.com`. Don't expect any other response though. DBAs won't be impressed by another developer trying to just move files around. As for the FILESTREAM folder, it won't have unrelated files unless an admin goes and exposes it, giving `Modify` access to random users. That's just sloppy

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos you're quite rude here. I get completely working database after my syncing. Just to clarify I'm working on low level - with files on file system. .mdf/.ldf etc it's just a files in the end. E.g. I can detach database copy and paste files somewhere and then I can attach and use the database normally from different location. `backup` and then what I need to do ? `restore`, right ? it's time consuming. My goal is minimal downtime

Answer (score 0):

As you may have noticed, your blob are stored in two folder in GUID.

f4bf1197-bb52-4246-95ba-4b7622065c19 is your table reference
4cf08168-3853-4c3d-ada2-4a1ff8d19900 is your column reference

If you have multiple blob, then you would have multiple sub folders.

You can probably derive a query from this aricle.

https://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/paul/filestream-directory-structure-where-do-the-guids-come-from/

```
SELECT
    [o].[name] AS [Table],
    [cp].[name] AS [Column],
    [p].[partition_number] AS [Partition],
    [r].[rsguid] AS [Rowset GUID],
    [rs].[colguid] AS [Column GUID]
FROM sys.sysrowsets [r] CROSS APPLY sys.sysrscols [rs]
JOIN sys.partitions [p]
    ON [rs].[rsid] = [p].[partition_id]
JOIN sys.objects [o]
    ON [o].[object_id] = [p].[object_id]
JOIN sys.syscolpars [cp]
    ON [cp].[colid] = [rs].[rscolid]
WHERE [rs].[colguid] IS NOT NULL
    AND [o].[object_id] = [cp].[id]
    AND [r].[rsguid] IS NOT NULL
    AND [r].[rowsetid] = [rs].[rsid];
GO
```

Do note that in new sql server edition, base tables are no longer easily available.

I would advise considering using filetables as other users have commented.

The following article will explain you how to get started.

https://www.sqlshack.com/sql-server-filetable-the-next-generation-of-sql-filestream/

- SQL server will do the leg work and present your filesteam as folder and files.
- the permission of you file table will be mirrored to the shared folder

Or you can just continue on your master.sys.xp_dirtree  technique.

https://www.patrickkeisler.com/2012/11/how-to-use-xpdirtree-to-list-all-files.html

assume that what you need is a file and 3 deep and is file as the $FSLOG are 2 deep

```
DECLARE @DirectoryTree TABLE (
    id INT IDENTITY(1, 1)
    ,subdirectory NVARCHAR(512)
    ,depth INT
    ,isfile BIT
    );

INSERT INTO @DirectoryTree
EXEC master.sys.xp_dirtree 'C:\PROGRAM FILES\MICROSOFT SQL SERVER\MSSQL14.SQLEXPRESS\MSSQL\DATA\FS'
    ,3
    ,1

SELECT *
FROM @DirectoryTree
WHERE depth = 3
    AND isfile = 1
```

Bare in mind that you may get duplicated file id. Do consider the FileTable alternative.

Comment: It's same what I've mantioned in my question actually. See the last part of my question. This approach does not guarantee that files which I got by executing  xp_dirtree EXEC is in use. In other words anyone can go to the blob folder and put there files which are not related to db

Comment: @isxaker anyone should *not* be able to do that at all. Anyone shouldn't have permissions to that folder in the first place, unless an admin exposed it on purpose. Even then, it should be just Read permissions. You can't ask the database to fix bad admin practices

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos yes it's fair enough. Perhaps I do not take care about such cases. But code in this answer is completely the same which I provided in my question

Comment: @isxaker follow the link. if you 'Enable FILESTREAM for file I/O access''  and the other settings.if you've done everything correctly, your files will be listed as a shared folder... what you are showing currently is the raw database file. not the actual file. tsql renames them to GUID and stores them in a hierarchy structure. xp_dirtree  is only a command shell command that list the file of any path on your server.

Comment: @FrankChen Of course I'd enabled it before I even wrote a question =) It's required actually. Please check bottom part of my question. It contains usage and output of master.sys.xp_dirtree. I mean I've already known about it. But it's not enough for me unfortunately.

Comment: @isxaker look at my answer, I am looking in the unified path that SQL will emulate your blob to a os readable path. You are looking in your c drive. Based on your question, you only have the last part done. 1. From SQL CFG you need to enable filesteam and give it a name. That will be your shared folder. In the example it is set to sql2019. 2. From sqms at the sever property you need to enable filesteam full. 3. This is the last part that you already done. At the DB level ad fs. If you've done everything correctly, from sqms, you can browse your file table from explore by left clicking it.

Comment: @FrankChen the only one difference in my example that I pass the path to the whole FS directory(`\localhost\sql2019\fs`) and in you example you pass path to blob folder(`\localhost\sql2019\fs\TestBlob`). Why are you insisting to enable file stream ? To clarify it is not possible to use file streams if it is not enabled. Other words I enabled FileStream when I started using my sql server. And name of my fileStream is `'FS'` - you can find it in t-sql script which I shared. And I believe there're a lot of cases when access to blob folder should be restricted in purpose(sharing is controversial)

Comment: @isxaker i see, i missed that only your column was in filestream. I will update my answer to the answer your looking for but it's no longer used in newer sql servers. Please considering using filestream file tables instead. each table will be visible as a shared folder and permission from the table will be mirrored to the folder

Comment: @isxaker EXEC master.sys.xp_dirtree 'C:\PROGRAM FILES\MICROSOFT SQL SERVER\MSSQL14.SQLEXPRESS\MSSQL\DATA\FS'    ,3    ,1 should do the trick. see the revised answer for the full explaination.